# Prolog - Filter List

Tags: list, filter, prolog

So I have this homework due tommorow. I have to filter every nth element of a list and return it as a list. So for example:

?- everyNth(3,[a,b,c,d,e,f],Rs).
Rs = [c,f].

My Idea was basically:

```
everynth(N, [X|Xs], L) :- everynth(N, [X|Xs], N, L).
everynth(N, [], C, L).
everynth(N, [X|Xs], 0, [X]) :- everynth(N, Xs, N, [X]).
everynth(N, [X|Xs], C, L) :- C1 is C -1,
  everynth(N,Xs,C1,L).
```

But it does not work this way, because in the third row it tries to match X and the return X and the Count 0 the second time it goes there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Check these modifications:

```
everynth(N, L, NL) :- everynth(N, L, N, NL).

everynth(_, [], _, []).
everynth(N, [X|Xs], 1, [X|NXs]) :- everynth(N, Xs, N, NXs).
everynth(N, [_|Xs], C, NXs) :- C1 is C-1, C1>0,
  everynth(N,Xs,C1,NXs).
```

The first clause of `everynth/4` is the termination of the recursion. It should give an empty list when there are no more items in the input list.

The second clause of `everynth/4` deals with the nth item, it has to put the input item in the output list and keep processing the remaining items restarting your item counter.

And the third clause of `everynth/4` deals with items which are not the nth element, so you have to skip the item, decrement the counter and continue with the remaining items.

Answer (score 1):

```
everynth(_, _, [], R, R).
everynth(1, M, [X|Xs], Z, R) :- append(Z, [X], Z1),  everynth(M, M, Xs, Z1, R).              
everynth(N, M, [_|Xs], Z, R) :- N > 1, N1 is N - 1, everynth(N1, M, Xs, Z, R).




?- everynth(3, 3, [a,b,c,d,e,f], [], Rs).
Rs = [c, f] .
```